# iphone : xcodebuild command from terminal not working, How to?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am running xcodebuild command from terminal but getting the following error

ATION (Release) ===
Check dependencies
error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphonesimulator3.1.3'
[BEROR]error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphonesimulator3.1.3'
** BUILD FAILED **

what is the possible reason i m getting this error ?. everything in XCode is working fine. if a run the project from XCode. it is working fine.

One thing to mention that i have not installed XCode in /Developer . i have created another folder in my system hard disk and there XCode is installed. is this thing related to the issue i m facing ??

Please acknowledge. waiting for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Install it to /Developer. It might make your life easier.
- Try `xcode-select /path/to/developer`. You haven't specified where you've installed it, so I can't help more.
- There is no iphonesimulator3.1.3 in the latest SDK. You could try `xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator4.0 ...`.

Comment: xcode-select worked like a charm. i am having 2 xcodes installed. xcode3.2.3 and xcode3.1.4. xcode-select was showing that default is xcode3.2.3 that does not have 3.1.3 sdk. so i changed my xcode to 3.1.4 using xcode-select and it worked. Thanx for your help.